# Stable sorting two files into one with the duplicates

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk, gawk

I've been trying to sort two files and get the output.

say for file 1:

```
102310863||7097881||6845123||271640||06007709532577||||
102310875||7092992||6840818||023740||10034500635650||||
```

and file 2:

```
102310863||7097881||6845193||271640||06007709532577||||
102310875||7092992||6840808||023740||10034500635650||||
```

The desired output is:

```
102310863||7097881||6845123||271640||06007709532577||||
102310863||7097881||6845193||271640||06007709532577||||
102310875||7092992||6840818||023740||10034500635650||||
102310875||7092992||6840808||023740||10034500635650||||
```

I've been trying to use the sort command

```
sort  -t \| -n -k1,1 t1.txt  t2.txt
```

but it is giving me the output

```
102310863||7097881||6845123||271640||06007709532577||||
102310863||7097881||6845193||271640||06007709532577||||
102310875||7092992||6840808||023740||10034500635650||||
102310875||7092992||6840818||023740||10034500635650||||
```

which is not what I want because original file order is not preserved.

Is there any other way of doing it to get the desired output?

Comment: but please check -k is specified for column 1..  so i'm getting wrong output.

Comment: i can understand that @kostya but how can i then format the code so that the output won't get affected?

Comment: sorry, my last comment was wrong. I miss understood the question. 

Probably you are looking for "-s" option (stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison)

Comment: yes.. that's perfect..  sort -s resolves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `-s` flag performs a stable sort.

```
sort  -s -t \|  -k1,1 t1.txt  t2.txt
```

From `man sort`:

> -s, --stable
>   stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison